# Retrieving data from map returns null

Tags: powershell, key-value

I'm trying to retrieve info from a map.

The map looks like this:

$VideoIDs:

```
[Object[7]]
[0]: @{Key=Load_Sheet; Value =}
[1]: @{Key=Load_Folded; Value =FormLoad}
[2]: @{Key=Load_Media; Value =}
...
```

(where the empty Values really should be that way)

This info is obtained similar to [get info from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71164647/regex-find-only-line-with-spaces-at-beginning/71166066?noredirect=1#comment125812515_71166066), except for the same keys, I'm getting VideoID instead of AlarmID.

I'm trying to retrieve the info for Load_Folded, and this is returning null, even though I can see it should be FormLoad.

```
$tmp = "Load_Folded"
$videoIdentifierString = $VideoIDs.$tmp  #gives null...same as if I do $VideoIDs[$tmp]   or $VideoIDs[$($tmp)]  or   $VideoIDs["$($tmp)"]
```

Any idea how to get this info out of the map?  I can't iterate over this map, and just need to obtain the value given the key.

This is with powershell 5.1 and VS Code.

Comment: `$result.where{ $_.Key -eq 'Load_Folded' }.Value` should be it

Comment: It's not a map btw, it's an array of `pscustomobject` if you're using the same code from that answer

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - I am using the same code.  Thank you!! That worked perfectly.

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes about filtering objects in an array in PowerShell, a good documentation to have a good concept on this is probably [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) even though there are many ways of accomplishing this some more efficient than others.

Given the array of `pscustomobject` you currently have:

```sh
$result = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{ Key = 'Load_Sheet';  Value = '' }
    [pscustomobject]@{ Key = 'Load_Folded'; Value = 'FormLoad' }
    [pscustomobject]@{ Key = 'Load_Media';  Value = '' }
)
```

- Using `Where-Object`:

```sh
($result | Where-Object Key -EQ 'Load_Folded').Value
```

- Using `.Where(..)`:

```sh
$result.Where({ $_.Key -eq 'Load_Folded' }).Value
```

- Using `foreach` and an `if` condition:

```sh
foreach($item in $result) {
    if($item.Key -eq 'Load_Folded') {
        $item.Value
    }
}
```